# Firebase, React and GitHub Actions: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy my React app to Firebase hosting via the GitHub Actions workflow configured via the Firebase CLI.

Although my app gets deployed, I don't see any content and I see the following error in the console,

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)
```

This is what my auto-generated `firebase-hosting-pull-request.yml` file looks like (the `firebase-hosting-merge.yml` file also looks similar),

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_MY_APP }}'
          projectId: my-app
```

I am configuring my Firebase as follows,

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const projectStorage = getStorage(app);
const projectFirestore = getFirestore(app);
const projectAuth = getAuth(app);

// Initialize Cloud Storage and get a reference to the service
export { projectStorage, projectFirestore, projectAuth };
```

When I am running locally, the env variables given above are placed in a `.env` file. I assumed (maybe incorrectly) that the above error is because these env variables are not available in my GitHub repository. So, I have added them as secrets and updated my `.yaml` files as shown below with an `env` section,

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_POOKIE_HUB }}'
          projectId: pookie-hub
        env:
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}'
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}'
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}'
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET }}'
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID }}'
          REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID: '${{ secrets.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID }}'
```

My problem still persists. What exactly is going on an how do I fix this?